# jQuery Tab charCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I was trying to figure out what the jQuery returns in the `event.which`, `event.keyCode`, event. during the blur event when I use tab key. Is it not supposed to return 9?. I also tried with the `keypress` but it does not recognize it.

http://jsfiddle.net/LvDGP/2/

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`keydown` should be used to capture a tab key.  `keypress` doesn't fire for TAB in all browsers and `blur` doesn't tell you what caused the object to lose focus.

```
$("#test").keydown(function(e){
    console.log("keydown: ",e);  //-> jQuery.Event > which: 9
});
```

> **Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LvDGP/3/**

Comment: All good advice, but I just want to add that `keypress` does fire for the tab key in some browsers (Firefox, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `keydown` or `keyup` to recognise the tab key:

```
$("#test").keydown(function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

That will log "9", as you expected. The reason for this is `keypress` only fires for character keys, whereas `keydown` will fire for all keys (such as TAB, arrow keys, etc.)

Comment: `keyup` might be a confusing approach to take, as it would fire for a field gaining focus as the result of tabbing into it, but not for a field losing focus as the result of tabbing out.

Comment: Yes, that's true. That's why I used `keydown` in the example. I just mentioned `keyup` for completeness, as it does also respond to non-character keys.